# Why does an object created via Object.create successfully log to the console in Chrome but not in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following code:

```
const personPrototype = {
    greeting: function() {
        return `Hello ${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    }
}

const bill = Object.create(personPrototype, {
    firstName: { value: 'Billy' },
    lastName: { value: 'Williams' },
});

console.log(bill);
bill.hasOwnProperty('firstName');
```

Returns the following when entered into the Chrome console:

```
{firstName: "Billy", lastName: "Williams"}
true
```

However, the same code in NodeJS returns:

```
{}
true
```

Why does logging the object in Node appear as an empty object when `bill.hasOwnProperty('lastName')` returns true?

Why is it different to Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is a result of the default behaviors of the `console` APIs in the browser and in Node.  In both environments, the `"firstName"` and `"lastName"` properties are added to your created objects as *non-enumerable* properties. The Node `console` API won't show you those unless you specifically ask it to: try

```
console.dir(bill, { showHidden: true });
```

The browser `console` API *will* show you the "own" non-enumerable properties.

Your objects are created the same in both cases.

If you want the properties to be enumerable, you'd do it the same way as you would with `Object.defineProperties()`:

```
const bill = Object.create(personPrototype, {
  firstName: {
    value: "billy",
    enumerable: true
  },
  lastName: {
    value: "williams",
    enumerable: true
  }
});
```